# Unity3D + protobuf-net: Could not load type of field Protobuf.BufferPool:_pool due to... System.Buffers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

I'm trying to use protobuf-net in Unity but I get the following exception when I try:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'ProtoBuf.BufferPool:_pool' (0) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. assembly:System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none>
ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter+StreamProtoWriter.CreateStreamProtoWriter (System.IO.Stream dest, ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel model, System.Object userState) (at <7f2f6774d3104e98a2359d5e5462b6bc>:0)
ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter+State.Create (System.IO.Stream dest, ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel model, System.Object userState) (at <7f2f6774d3104e98a2359d5e5462b6bc>:0)
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T] (System.IO.Stream destination, T instance, System.Object userState) (at <bd1d3a3f27ab42199d646f1541550b36>:0)
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T] (System.IO.Stream destination, T instance) (at <bd1d3a3f27ab42199d646f1541550b36>:0)
ProtobufNetTest.Awake () (at Assets/Tests/Protobuf-net/ProtobufNetTest.cs:26)
```

I've installed protobuf-net using [nuget for unity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity/releases/tag/v2.0.1).  The test script I'm using looks like this:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;


[ProtoContract]
public class ProtobufTestItself
{
    [ProtoMember( 1 )]
    public int IntMember { get; set; }

}

public class ProtobufNetTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        var test = new ProtobufTestItself();

        test.IntMember = 313373;

        byte[] bytes = null;

        using ( var memoryStream = new MemoryStream() )
        {
            Serializer.Serialize( memoryStream, test );

            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        using ( var memoryStream = new MemoryStream( bytes ) )
        {
            var roundTripped = Serializer.Deserialize<ProtobufTestItself>( memoryStream );

            Debug.Log( "Round tripped: " + roundTripped.IntMember.ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```

And this is using Unity 2019.4.15f1.

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Hi; I'm the library author, but simply: I'm not a unity person. I can barely string together 3 lines of unity. If someone can advise on ways to make unity happy, I'll be more than willing to look at whether it can be integrated, but: I'm not the source of knowledge in what those things are

Comment: Hah; thanks Marc!  For what it's worth, I've seen your name around and I have a lot of respect for you and your work.  Thanks for what looks like a great library.

I don't know if helps, but the only clue I have here is that the error message mentions "System.Buffers 4.0.2.0" but the nuget package seems to be pulling in System.Buffers.4.5.1?  I'm not enough of a C# head to know if that's the issue though.

Comment: The package version number and the assembly version number *do not need to match*; this sounds like an "assembly binding redirects" problem - does unity use assembly binding redirects?

Comment: Interesting it sounds like it's something they're working.  https://forum.unity.com/threads/binding-redirects-policy-file-support.943864/

There's another thread someone has where they have a workaround for creating an app config: https://forum.unity.com/threads/dependency-on-newtonsoft-json.814128/

I can take a stab at that.  What do I need to put in the assembly binding redirect to make this work?  Sorry, C# isn't my bread and butter.

Comment: and unity isn't mine, so honestly: I don't know! I won't miss them when they disappear for good